# Scale a UIView Horizontally

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, scale, bounds

I'm trying to scale a view Horizontally but i'm not getting the results i expected.

```
view.bounds = CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x, view.bounds.origin.y , view.bounds.size.width * scaleX, view.bounds.size.height );
view.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.origin.x, view.center.y);
```

As you can see at the code above, i want to scale the view just to the right side. This is why i changed the center of the view.

The problem is that the view stills scaling to both sides!
I did the same logic to scale another UIView vertically and got the result i expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the problem.

when setting certer, the new point must be relative to frame, not bounds.
so, i get the code:

```
view.center = CGPointMake(-view.frame.origin.x, view.center.y);
```

Hope it helps somebody..

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

If the origin of your view's frame is in the top-left (which is the default), increasing the width of your view should scale it to the right only.

This should work:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width * scaleX, view.frame.size.height);
```

You do not need to adjust the origin/center point to scale only to the right.

Comment: Yes, i need to re-center the view. doing what you said, the view grows to both sides.

Comment: @FelipeConde really?? I just made a completely new project with a view and a button, hooked the button up to a method with that code in, and it only scaled to the right... I don't understand why it doesn't do that for you... have you checked where the origin of your view is? - If you still can't get it to work I'll upload some sample code somewhere which you can download to test it with

Comment: I just pasted your code and got the view growing to both sides. I found a solution, you can see it above. I`ve just answer my own question. Thx for you help ;)

Comment: @FelipeConde I know you've found a solution, but you shouldn't need to reset the center. Can you check where your view's origin is?

Comment: The view origin getting it thought bounds was 0,0 as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an affine transform instead:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, 1)
```

And then setting the center.

Comment: Affine transformation just zoom the view. The view still with the same values to bounds as before. =/